# Как отправить форму с помощью ajax при использовании onblur

Tags: php

Всем дратути, сегодня столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Имеется input с onblur

```
<input type="text" name="text" onblur="submit()">
```

Он обёрнут в форму

```
<form method="post"> <!-- тут input --> </form>
```

Смотрел на многих сайтах везде был скрипт при нажатии кнопки, но в целом `onblur="submit()"` и означает невидимое ее нажатие, но ничего не сработало. Посоветуйте как сделать это без перезагрузки и подаче данных скрипту php с помощью Ajax.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А как именно [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) не отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо большое